# download files from bundle on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am working on an app in which i have 9 pdf files in a directory in app bundle and i want to download the files on button click . Brief information what i want to achieve- if i enter any 2 digit number in the textfield and click on submit the logic breaks the 2 digit value by adding it to form single value(1-9)if the output of 2 digit number is 1 the number goes to switch case and displays the output pdf file on textview for that case and below the textview there is a save button how i download that pdf fle on save button click.
"

```
(IBAction)btnc:(id)sender { if([_textfield.text intValue]>31 &&[_textfield.text intValue]>0)

{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Please Enter Correct Details." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    UIAlertAction* OK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                         }];
    [alert addAction:OK];

}
else{

    {
        int sum, i ,j ;
        sum=0;
        sum= [_textfield.text intValue];
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            j=sum%10;
            sum=sum/10;
            sum=sum+j;
        }

        for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            j=sum%10;
            sum=sum/10;
            sum=sum+j;
        }
        NSLog(@"%i",sum);
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];

        self.lb.text = str;

        switch(sum)
        {
            case 1 :

                NSLog(@"1\n" );
                break;
            case 2 :

                NSLog(@"2\n" );
                break;
            case 3 :

                NSLog(@"3\n" );
                break;
            case 4 :

                NSLog(@"4\n" );
                break;
            case 5 :

                NSLog(@"5\n" );
                break;
            case 6 :

                NSLog(@"6\n" );
                break;
            case 7 :

                NSLog(@"7\n" );
                break;
            case 8 :

                NSLog(@"8" );
                break;
            case 9 :

                NSLog(@"9 \n" );
                break;
            default :

                NSLog(@"incorrect\n" );
        }

        DescriptionViewController *face = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Description"];
        [face setStr:[self descriptionForSum:sum]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:face animated:YES];
    }
}}

    - (NSString *)descriptionForSum:(int)sum{
NSString * returnedDescription = @"";
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me%d", sum] ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"Text"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

if (myData) {
    returnedDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return returnedDescription;
}
return returnedDescription; }
```

if user clicks on save button for the output 1 as in the image the pdf file with me1.pdf will start download if the output is 2 then the file me2.pdf will start download.

Comment: if the file in your bundle then why you are download? are you want show the file PDF file in pdf reader?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I want to save the pdf in user device and want to make it shareable.

Comment: If you save the PDF in bundle then user can be share this PDF using QuickLook framework

Comment: User can share the PDF on email ID and download in device from email

Comment: I can understand your problem but if a PDF in your app bundle then it also user application, so user easily view the PDF and share, According to you user cannot download PDF from your app in device storage that's why we use QuickLook framework. Please check my answer and try it.

Comment: is my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You show to the PDF in QuickLook Frame work:
On Save button:

```
QLPreviewController *previewVC = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        previewVC.delegate = self;
        previewVC.dataSource = self;
        [self presentViewController:previewVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Quicklook Delegate:**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller{
    return 1;
}

-(id<QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    @try {
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        return fileUrl;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error In Func:%s and line:%d with reason:%@",__func__,__LINE__,exception.reason);
    }
}
```

In the quick look view controller you show the share icon where user can share the PDF.
For more reference: https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/, http://kratinmobile.com/blog/index.php/document-preview-in-ios-with-quick-look-framework/

Comment: I have a save button in my app , the pdf files is in the bundle and the content of that file is displaying on the textview according to the output ,the output is 1 the content of file 1.pdf will be displayed on textview and when the user clicks on save button the file 1.pdf will start download in user iphone or saves in user phone and a alert or popup comes over with a message download successfull

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But unable to solve the issue with your answer.

Comment: Ok, My pleasure. I try my best. Happy Coding :) @itsKamal

Comment: saurabhaceitj@gmail.com please send here @itsKamal